# Setting up Hadoop Cluster - NameNode smoke test "Unable to connect"

Tags: hadoop

I am having trouble connection to my NameNode server from another server on the cluster.  the namenode starts fine and i can get to the namenode dashboard browsing to `http://localhost:50070`, but trying to browse to `http://hadoop-cluster-1:50070` or even using the IP address doesn't work.  I am able to ping hadoop-cluster-1 and the IP address.  I am also able to traceroute the port and host all from the server that i am getting an "Unable to connect" in Firefox.  See below for values files.

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-cluster-1.com:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
    <value>8192</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-cluster-1:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-cluster-1:8020</value>
    <description>The port where the NameNode runs the HDFS protocol.
                     Combined with the NameNode's hostname to build its address.
    </description>
  </property> 
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
    <value>hadoop-cluster-1:8020</value>
    <description>
            RPC address that handles all clients requests. In the case of HA/Federation where multiple namenodes exist, the name ser
vice id is added to the name e.g. dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns1 dfs.namenode.rpc-address.EXAMPLENAMESERVICE The value of this propert
y will take the form of nn-host1:rpc-port.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///data/nn1,file:///data/nn2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>131072</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///data/data1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you show me your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: I figured it out to be the /etc/sysconfig/iptables were not allowing the port.